# MPAndroidChart: Rotate Labels of X-Axis by 90 degrees in BarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

My text in xAxes of BarChart from [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) is too long. How I can rotate label of xAxes by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 35):

Now it is possible in library version 2.1.6

try this

```
XAxis xAxis=barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45);
```

Comment: @Phillip How do I rotate them only when my labels doesn't fit the screen size

Comment: Base your angle on the amount of data you have. Say if 6 values fit then dont set the rotation till number of values cross 6 and then after that increase the angle gradually till you reach 90

Comment: @user1615184 If this answer helped you plz do mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5):

It is simple, try this...

```
XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(90);
```

Comment: text overlaps on another text. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

you can hide you xAxis label and put custom text view which is Vertical. 
Here is code for Vertical Text view.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
final boolean topDown;

public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    final int gravity = getGravity();
    if (Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        setGravity((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
        topDown = false;
    } else
        topDown = true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

    canvas.save();

    if (topDown) {
        canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
        canvas.rotate(90);
    } else {
        canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
        canvas.rotate(-90);
    }

    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

}

Comment: How can i do it in MPChartAndroid?

Comment: Put you Chart to one layout and place this textview to left of chart. and Hide xAxis lable. I have used this pattern for My Barchart.

Comment: No dear piyush. My Mean was not xAxis lable. it was all XAxis lables that are depend on Xvalues. Did you get it?

Comment: ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   xVals.add(Integer.toString(i) );
  }

Answer (score 0):

Just override `XAxisRenderer` and `renderAxisLabels(c: Canvas)` method.

And set it to barChart `itemView.barChart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomBarChartRenderer(itemView.barChart.viewPortHandler, itemView.barChart.xAxis, itemView.barChart.rendererXAxis.transformer))`

```
    import android.graphics.Canvas
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRenderer
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer

class CustomBarChartRenderer(viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler, xAxis: XAxis, trans: Transformer) : XAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans) {

    override fun renderAxisLabels(c: Canvas) {

        if (!mXAxis.isEnabled || !mXAxis.isDrawLabelsEnabled)
            return

        val yoffset = mXAxis.yOffset

        mAxisLabelPaint.typeface = mXAxis.typeface
        mAxisLabelPaint.textSize = mXAxis.textSize
        mAxisLabelPaint.color = mXAxis.textColor

        val pointF = MPPointF.getInstance(0f, 0f)
        if (mXAxis.position == XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP) {
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 1.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentTop() - yoffset, pointF)

        } else if (mXAxis.position == XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE) {
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 1.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentBottom() - yoffset, pointF)

        } else if (mXAxis.position == XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM) {
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 0.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentBottom() + yoffset, pointF)

        } else if (mXAxis.position == XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE) {
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 0.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentBottom() - yoffset - mXAxis.mLabelRotatedHeight.toFloat(), pointF)

        } else { // BOTH SIDED
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 1.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentTop() - yoffset, pointF)
            pointF.x = 0.5f
            pointF.y = 0.0f
            drawLabels(c, mViewPortHandler.contentBottom() + yoffset, pointF)
        }
        MPPointF.recycleInstance(pointF)
    }
}
```